# cpp vector for loop termination condition error

Tags: c++, c++11

When compiling the below function, following is the compilation error. why is `yt != endIx` in the 2nd for loop illegal.

> error C2678: binary '!=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::_Vector_iterator>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

```
void printDebug(vector <int>  ar)
{
    for (auto it = ar.begin(); it != ar.end(); it++)
    {
        auto endIx = ar.end() - it;
        for (auto yt = ar.begin(); yt != endIx ; yt++)
        {
            cout << *it << " : " << endIx ;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Just to avoid confusion i have renamed the auto end iterator to endIx;

Answer (score 9):

The type of `ar.end() - it` is `std::vector<int>::difference_type` (a [container trait](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) giving the type of the distance between iterators), it is **not** an iterator.

Use iterator arithmetic with `ar.begin() + end` in your loop instead :

```
void printDebug(vector <int>  ar)
{
    for (auto it = ar.begin(); it != ar.end(); it++)
    {
        auto end = ar.end() - it; // end is of type vector <int>::difference_type
        for (auto yt = ar.begin(); yt != ar.begin() + end; yt++)
        {
            cout << *it << " : " << end;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

---

**Note:**

You should pass your vector by const reference, not by value :

```
void printDebug(const vector<int>&  ar)
{
    for (auto it = ar.begin(); it != ar.end(); it++)
    {
        auto end = ar.end() - it; // end is of type vector <int>::difference_type
        for (auto yt = ar.begin(); yt != ar.begin() + end; yt++)
        {
            cout << *it << " : " << end;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: The notes ("pass by const reference", and "pass by a pair of iterators") are unrelated to the problem and IMO distracting

Comment: Meh, pair of iterators may be more of a question of style, but I'd definitely make a note that the vector should be passed by const ref rather than value.

Comment: @T.C. agree, added back